# interoperability between Python and R

Tags: r, reticulate

What is the supossed way to read variables from Python (using `reticulate`) from inside a R function?
Since the Python session cannot access variables that are in the environment of the function, is the only way copying them to the global environment?

```r
library(reticulate)
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(123, 234), col2 = c(233, 283))

py_run_string("print (r.df1)")
#>     col1   col2
#> 0  123.0  233.0
#> 1  234.0  283.0

fun <- function(x) {
  # create a new variable with a random name in the global environment
  tmp_var_name <- str_c(sample(letters, 30, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
  message(tmp_var_name)
  assign(tmp_var_name, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  # Python can read from that global variable
  py_run_string(glue("print (r.{tmp_var_name})"))
  
  # finally, delete the variable
  remove(list = tmp_var_name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

fun(df1)
#> vemcjnbxvnfvbdgushqkjcmtgzwhpu
#>     col1   col2
#> 0  123.0  233.0
#> 1  234.0  283.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs weren't helping, so I went to the source, which led me to discover [the internal `py_resolve_envir()` function](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/4967abddb35865a1be6ad839298695f1481bcade/R/python.R#L1334-L1357) which in the example in the question will return the R global environment, but won't always.

In particular, its first section is

```r
  # if an environment has been set, use it
  envir <- getOption("reticulate.engine.environment")
  if (is.environment(envir))
    return(envir)
```

meaning you can pass an environment to an option called `reticulate.engine.environment`, and reticulate will use that instead of the global environment as the place that gets searched when you try to subset into `r` in python.

Thus, you can write:

```r
set.seed(47L)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(123, 234), col2 = c(233, 283))

fun <- function(x) {
  e <- new.env()
  options("reticulate.engine.environment" = e)
  
  # create a new variable with a random name
  tmp_var_name <- paste(sample(letters, 30, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
  message(tmp_var_name)
  assign(tmp_var_name, x, envir = e)
  
  res <- reticulate::py_run_string(glue::glue("print( r.{tmp_var_name} )"))
  options("reticulate.engine.environment" = NULL)  # unset option
  invisible(res)
}

fun(df1)
#> zjtvorkmoydsepnxkabmeondrjaanu
#>     col1   col2
#> 0  123.0  233.0
#> 1  234.0  283.0
```

to avoid needing to put everything in the global environment.

---

#### Coda: Arbitrary R code execution from Python

If you call `dir()` on `r`, it has a `__getitem__` method defined which is what is getting called when you do `r.{tmp_var_name}`:

```r
reticulate::py_run_string('print( dir(r) )')
#> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']

reticulate::py_run_string('print( r.__getitem__ )')
#> <bound method make_python_function.<locals>.python_function of <__main__.R object at 0x111b0b6a0>>

x <- 47L
reticulate::py_run_string('print( r.__getitem__("x") )')
#> 47
```

The definition of this is [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/4967abddb35865a1be6ad839298695f1481bcade/R/python.R#L1305-L1320). Notably, `getter()` calls its second parameter `code` for a reason:

```r
  getter <- function(self, code) {
    envir <- py_resolve_envir()
    object <- eval(parse(text = as_r_value(code)), envir = envir)
    r_to_py(object, convert = is.function(object))
  }
```

—it gets passed to `eval(parse(text = ...))`, which will turn any string into R code and run it. That means you can pass *any R code* into `r.__getitem__()`, with a limitation that it must return something that can be converted to a python type (e.g. not an environment or a model), and a more superficial limitation that it cannot contain newlines. But that still lets you execute arbitrary code in R:

```r
reticulate::py_run_string("print( r.__getitem__('head(iris)') )")
#>    Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
#> 0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
#> 1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
#> 2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
#> 3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
#> 4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
#> 5           5.4          3.9           1.7          0.4  setosa

reticulate::py_run_string("print( r.__getitem__('broom::tidy(lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars))') )")
#>           term   estimate  std.error  statistic       p.value
#> 0  (Intercept)  30.098861   1.633921  18.421246  6.642736e-18
#> 1           hp  -0.068228   0.010119  -6.742389  1.787835e-07

# this method also gets called if you subset `r` with `[]`:
reticulate::py_run_string("print( r['library(tidyverse); mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(across(everything(), mean))'] )")
#>    cyl        mpg        disp    ...           am      gear      carb
#> 0  4.0  26.663636  105.136364    ...     0.727273  4.090909  1.545455
#> 1  6.0  19.742857  183.314286    ...     0.428571  3.857143  3.428571
#> 2  8.0  15.100000  353.100000    ...     0.142857  3.285714  3.500000
#> 
#> [3 rows x 11 columns]
```

This code will get called from whatever environment `py_resolve_envir()` returns, but if you can access (or make!) the thing you want from there, you can grab it.

Also this feels enough like a SQL injection attack suggesting that you *really* shouldn't let a user pick variable names if you're running this in Shiny or similar, but I don't expect that's likely anyway.

Comment: Tnanks. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just do an assignment inside the function and extract the `list` with `py$`

```
fun <- function(x) {
  # create a new variable with a random name in the global environment
  tmp_var_name <- str_c(sample(letters, 30, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
  message(tmp_var_name)
  assign(tmp_var_name, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  # Python can read from that global variable
  py_run_string(glue("x1 = r.{tmp_var_name}"))
  
  # finally, delete the variable
  remove(list = tmp_var_name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  py$x1
}
```

-testing

```
fun(df1)
#galdlxvgjpxuzkvmwznspxjdrftcmu
#$col2
#[1] 233 283

#$col1
#[1] 123 234
```

Comment: So I understand that, for now, the way to communicate between R and Python is by reading and writing on global variables (which both have access to).

Comment: @crestor you don't need to assign it to globalenv

Comment: I think it's neccesary to assign to the global environment, which is the only one the Python session has access to. At least, as far as I know.

Comment: @crestor may be you are right.  i was thinking that you could also create a new env and assign it

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to wait a bit to see if there are more answers. And if not, I'll mark yours as chosen.