# Best way to access R-objects using py_run_string for use in R package

Tags: r, reticulate

I am developing a package that needs to access user-created R-objects from within Python.  Unfortunately, users in R can create objects with symbols that Python does not like (e.g. df$col.name).  When I form a string to be executed by Python, accessing those objects (e.g. `reticulate::py_run_string("print(r.df.col.name)")` yields an error.

Any suggested workarounds?  I have an R-environment called `cacheEnv` where I store stuff for R outside of the global environment, but I can't seem to access it using `reticulate::py_run_string()`.  As my package is destined for CRAN, I need to find a solution that does not rely on creating new objects in the global enivornment as I demonstrate in the example below.  Thanks!

```
library(reticulate)
## create R object with bad python name
goodNameObject = c(10,9,8,7)
bad.NameObject = c(1,2,3,4)

## access objects from python
reticulate::py_run_string("print(r.goodNameObject)")

## bad name object causes error
reticulate::py_run_string("print(r.bad.NameObject)")
# get error: Error in eval(parse(text = as_r_value(code)), envir = envir) : RuntimeError: object 'bad' not found

## my workaround - create new object in Global Env
badNameObject = bad.NameObject
reticulate::py_run_string("print(r.badNameObject)")

## how can I access the bad.NameObject using py_run_string() without creating a new variable in R's global environment?  I am developing a package that has to handle badly formed names and CRAN does not like global variables to be created by a package.
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered from here [interoperability between Python and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67562889/interoperability-between-python-and-r):

that

> "you can pass an environment to an option called reticulate.engine.environment, and reticulate will use that instead of the global environment as the place that gets searched when you try to subset into r in python."

This led me to a nice solution that seems to work for me:

```
library(reticulate)
cacheEnv <- new.env()
options("reticulate.engine.environment" = cacheEnv)

## create R objects
globalObject = "hello"
bad.NameObject = c(1,2,3)

## rename poorly named object in cacheEnv
assign("renamedObject",bad.NameObject,envir = cacheEnv)

## ensure access to all objects from python
reticulate::py_run_string("print(r.renamedObject)")
reticulate::py_run_string("print(r.globalObject)")
```

Hope this helps someone.  I'd be interested in other workarounds if you think of them.